# How do Install 32 Bit Firefox alongside 64 bit Firefox on 64 bit 11.10 machine?

Tags: firefox, webex

Need to run Webex Audio/Video. Am running the Sun version of Java, but apparently the Webex plugins will not work on 64 bit. Another member posted info on how to use 32 bit plugin, but I'd rather not muck with my good working install. I'd be OK with running a different browser ONLY when I need Webex. I am currently using Firefox 11 (64 bit) and Chromium 17.0 (64 bit).

Can anyone point me towards how I would install Firefox 32 alongside 64, or Chrome (32 bit) alongside Chromium (64 bit)... or some other 32-bit browser variant that would allonw Webex audio/video to work alongside my current setup..

Comment: When I run in to really finicky plug-ins, I install them inside a windows browser in wine.

Comment: Gave Firefox via Playonlinux a try... and seemed to almost work, but never quite connected...

Comment: This looked promising, but the script to set Firefox and Java environment seems to be ignored in Ubuntu... http://linuxsagas.digitaleagle.net/2011/11/10/webex-in-fedora-15-64-bit/#comments

Comment: let me look in to that...it does look like a way to get it working...

Comment: as my answer is poor, its a comment: install 11.10 inside a virtualbox. 64-bit firefox out of it, 32-bit firefox inside of it. Not a good idea?

Comment: Obviously always an option, but one does take a performance hit in doing this. Nicer to run this natively if possible. My answer below does work, and it is native (and not hard to do).

Comment: closely related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21460/how-can-i-install-firefox-4-nightlies-and-firefox-3-6-stable-on-the-same-system

Comment: nice you found a solution!

Comment: remember to choose it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a bunch of experimentation, but this DEFINITELY works for Webex audio and was pretty straight forward.

http://blog.romera.org/2012/03/09/make-webex-work-in-ubuntu-11-10-64-bit/

Nice thing about it is that you preserve everything in Firefox as is... Not sure if video works, but I will confirm that once I play a bit more.

Comment: The above solution doesn't appear to work for video (at least for me). Would love to hear from anyone who has figured out a way around that. Would love to NOT have to run Windows :-)

Answer (score 1):

To install a standalone 32 bit version of Firefox next to the default 64 bit system version of Firefox and have it use a standalone 32 bit Java plugin, check out [the answer of Fholst](https://askubuntu.com/a/202415/2217) to [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/111947/2217).